# Laravel - Advanced Carbon Date Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to write a certain query but I'm failing with it and I'm looking for some help

Here's what I want to do

> SELECT all items WHERE **created_at** is from before this month (July, June,...), *and* *also* select the first 3 which are created during this month

this is what I currently have. I've tried numerous times, but I can't figure out the right "WHERE" case

```
   $offertes = DB::table('offertes')
      ->select('*')
      ->where('receiver_id', $user_id)
...
      ->orderby('seen')
      ->orderby('created_at','desc')
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$time = new Carbon\Carbon('first day of this month'); // Get first day of the month.
$time->setTime(0, 0, 0); // Set time to 00:00:00.
....
->where('created_at', '<', $time)
->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('created_at', '>', $time)
      ->orderby('created_at','asc') 
      ->take(3)
})
->get;
```

Comment: Where do you take the first 3 of the current month then? I editted the OP to make it a bit more clear